# The recommended way to remove a redundant part from a symbolic ordinary differential equation

Tags: matlab, ode

I am using  the MATLAB tool called 'dsolve' to solve an ODE but I can't solve it because I have more question than I need. Like in my case I need only the fist 2 equations but I have 4. The question is how to delete it it using the symbolic tool.

```
odequations = [diff(h(t), t, t) == (26*h(t))/25 
                   (11683563954355*theta(t))/1099511627776;

         diff(theta(t), t, t) == (4296857747895619*theta(t))/562949953421312 - 
           (400*h(t))/1043;

         0 == 0;

         0 == 0]
```

I have tried simplify(odequations) but with no success.

My error message is as seen below.

```
Error using mupadengine/feval (line 187)
Invalid initial conditions.

Error in dsolve>mupadDsolve (line 340)
T = feval(symengine,'symobj::dsolve',sys,x,options);

Error in dsolve (line 194)
sol = mupadDsolve(args, options);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`isAlways`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/isalways.html) to remove redundant equations.

```
>> syms a
>> eqs = [a == 10;
    a == a;
    0 == 0];
>> eqs(isAlways(eqs)) = []
eqs =
a == 10
```

`isAlways` will throw a warning for equations that are not redundant, which you can supress by calling:

```
isAlways(eqs,'Unknown','false')
```

Comment: Awesome. Works well.